# How can I write a cyclic RDF graph in JSON-LD?

Tags: rdf, json-ld

My graph is the follow:

```
  [Natasha]--- knows--> [Bob]
  [Bob]--- brother of--> [Alice]
  [Alice]--- play with--> [Natasha]
```

How can I embed it in JSON-LD?

My current solution that doesn't work:

```json
{
"@context" : {
   "Natasha" : "http://names.example.org/resource/name/Natasha",
   "Bob" : "http://names.example.org/resource/name/Bob",
   "Alice" : "http://names.example.org/resource/name/Alice",
   "knows" : "http://example.com/knows",
   "brother-of" : "http://example.com/brother-of",
   "play-with" : "http://example.com/play-with"
},
 "@id" : "Natasha", 
  "knows" : 
        {  "@id" : "Bob", 
           "brother-of" : { 
                    "@id" : "Alice",
              "play-with" : "Natasha"
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This value gets interpreted as plain text, not as URI:

```json
"play-with" : "Natasha"
```

To get it interpreted as URI, you can either define it in your context:

```json
"@context": {
  "play-with": {
    "@id": "http://example.com/play-with", 
    "@type": "@id"
  }
}
```

Or you can make it explicit when providing a value (like you already do for `brother-of`):

```json
"play-with" : {"@id": "Natasha"}
```

Comment: I'd go with always providing id for all references. Then systems can stitch together the relationships. That way you can also define each entities details separately and only reference the entities id when defining relationships.